# WPF DatePicker to show the time as well as the date

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have a `DatePicker` object in a `DataGrid` that successfully shows the date from the database or a property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
   </DataTemplate>   
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Now I want to show the time in front of the date. This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}"/>
   </DataTemplate>   
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

NOTE: I do **not** want to do this in the code-behind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the extended
[DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker)

Comment: So I am guessing by your answer that this cannot be done using the .NET Library?

Comment: The `DatePicker` control does not deal with time, only dates. So you will need to use a different control.

Comment: Unfortunately, since version 4.0.0, this is only for non commercial use. Commercial use requires a license that costs over 600$.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to, without using other components, **if you just want to display a date** in the format that you want to edit it, you can do this:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Date,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="YourDate">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding YourDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            <TextBox Margin="2 0 0 0" Text="{Binding YourDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='t'}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourDate}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This will show an DatePicker next to an TextBox wich are bound to the same property. The TextBox got an StringFormat to only show the date.

UpdateSourceTrigger is set to PropertyChanged, so the user can't do an conflict.