# Why does WPF calendar return a time when there is no time picker?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

WHy does the value of `calendar.SelectedDate` include a time (eg.: 22-04-2022 00:00:00) when the user has picked a date?
In fact, I am interested in picking both a date and time but apparently, from what I've read, it seems like you can't pick a time from the calendar element in the program UI and I don't understand why when it also returns time in the value of `Selected.Date`

Is there an option to extend the calendar element to also include a timer-picker that isn't too complicated?

Code that that that returns returns `dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00`

```
        {
            post.date = calendar.SelectedDate.ToString();
            DateLabel.Content = $"Date and time for post: {post.date}";
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF DatePicker to show the time as well as the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764111/wpf-datepicker-to-show-the-time-as-well-as-the-date)

Answer (score 1):

WPF calendar has the default DateTime property. Neither only Date nor only Time it has `Nullable<DateTime>` default property, so it always along with Time. You would avoid it by setting below code

```
post.date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.toString() support formatting the date and time and this can be use to get only date not time as shown in the below code.

```
   post.date = calendar.sele.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   DateLabel.Content = $"Date and time for post: {post.date}";
```

Answer (score 0):

> WHy does the value of calendar.SelectedDate include a time (eg.: 22-04-2022 00:00:00) when the user has picked a date?

Simply because there is no date-only data type available in .NET and the `Calendar` control uses the `DateTime` type to store the selected date. That's why.

> it seems like you can't pick a time from the calendar element in the program UI

Correct.

> Is there an option to extend the calendar element to also include a timer-picker that isn't too complicated?

No.